# Is it possible to change ImageView ID dynamically?

Tags: android, imageview

I am facing a problem with my 2 listeners that listen to the same ImageView ID. Thinking to only enable 1 of them during menu click, and hide the other 1.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your View is part of a custom View hierarchy then you shouldn't do it because of possible conflict. I think what you really want to do is not to have two listeners but change the content of a same listener based on a click. Why not simply use `if` ?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. You can call `View.setId(int)` and `View.getId()` to set and get a `View`'s id. But `change ImageView ID dynamically` is not recommended at all. Because conflicts of different views are easy to happen if you do so.